# In jQuery, what happens when I "$.when.apply($, [...])"...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a JS package to be used as part of a larger application, in which there are times that an unknown number of API calls need to be made in a group, parsing the responses for all calls in the group at the same time.

Whenever dealing with multiple Ajax calls that should be handled together (using jQuery), it makes sense to use `$.when().done()`, but because I don't know how many calls are needed ahead of time, I had to resort to using `.apply()` to put them all *into* the `$.when()` call.

Quick note: I have values generated inside the same function that starts the Ajax call, which I need returned to the function that calls it.. Hence the strange looking `return [...]` section. FWIW: my code is not broken, the end result is exactly as I want, but I really hate using code that I don't yet understand...

The code in question looks like:

```
var requestsMap = {
  group1: ["call1"],
  group2: ["call1", "call2"],
  group3: ["call2", "call4", "call6"]
};

var requests = requestsMap[REQUEST_INPUT].map(function(_type) {
  return ajaxCallWrapper(REQUEST_CONFIG, _type);
});

$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
  // see comment after code block
});

function ajaxCallWrapper(_config, _type) {
  var customUrl = _config[_type].url;
  var extra1 = "...";
  var extra2 = "...";
  return [$.ajax({
    url: customUrl,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    global: false
  }), {
    extra1: extra1,
    extra2: extra2
  }];
}
```

When I first found out about `$.when()`, I did take note of the different response pattern (`data, textStatus, jqXHR`) when using multiple promises. As a result, I thought I may need to do something like...

```
var responses = requests.length === 1 ? [arguments] : arguments;
```

...when I get the responses in `.done()` so that I could loop over each response as a callback argument. But even with only one Ajax call, I can still get the data, text status and XHR object from the first callback argument.

Any chance someone could explain why this is?

---

Edit for clarification. See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4pj1nnw8/1/) for reference.

---

Final edit - tried to use the same code in my own answer, but SO didn't like that..

Comment: So you're essentially asking why you can loop over a set of data when there is only one element in that set? Isn't it because the loop just runs one time?

Comment: For reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/  When `requests.length` equals 1, arguments will contain whatever the request was resolved with. If it is more than one, then it will contain an array. You seem to be suggesting otherwise?

Comment: @ObsidianAge, I'm asking why the following example from the docs doesn't apply when my code only has one Ajax call: `$.when( $.ajax( "test.aspx" ) ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR )`.. I thought that part of my question was pretty clear. :/

Comment: I'm still confused as to what you're actually asking for. Passing only one request returns you only one response. The first parameter, `data`, in itself contains the `statusCode` and `jqXHR`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge, please see the edit to my question.

Comment: @ObsidianAge, apparently I missed one vital point in my own code before posting this question... While it does indeed have cases where only one Ajax call is made, the demo examples I was working through earlier didn't have any iterations with only one Ajax call, so *all* of them were coming back with the same structure. It's been a rough couple weeks, apparently I'm not thinking straight right now. If I could, I'd even downvote my own question now.. :(

Comment: Please don't add requests for people not to answer your questions! While a question is open for answers, anyone is permitted to answer. If you solved it yourself, then that's good - perhaps posting the question was the rubber-ducking you needed?

Comment: @halfer, yup.. That's logical, sorry. I'm really just not thinking straight at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg... Serious facepalm moment. I apologise profusely, no idea how I missed this one.

Going back to the [JSFiddle I created just now](https://jsfiddle.net/4pj1nnw8/4/):

```
var d1 = $.ajax("/css/light.css");
var d2 = $.ajax("/css/light.css");
var d3 = $.ajax("/css/light.css");
$.when(d1, d2, d3).done(function (v1, v2, v3) {
    console.log("v1:", v1);
    console.log("v2:", v2);
    console.log("v3:", v3);
});

var d4 = $.ajax("/css/light.css");
$.when(d4).done(function (v4a, v4b, v4c) {
    console.log("v4a:", v4a);
    console.log("v4b:", v4b);
    console.log("v4c:", v4c);
});

var d5 = [$.ajax("/css/light.css")];
$.when.apply($, d5).done(function (v5a, v5b, v5c) {
    console.log("v5a:", v5a);
    console.log("v5b:", v5b);
    console.log("v5c:", v5c);
});

var d6 = [$.ajax("/css/light.css"), $.ajax("/css/light.css")];
$.when.apply($, d6).done(function (v6a, v6b, v6c) {
    console.log("v6a:", v6a);
    console.log("v6b:", v6b);
    console.log("v6c:", v6c);
});
```

Shows the following output in the console:

```
v1: (3) ["", "success", {…}]
v2: (3) ["", "success", {…}]
v3: (3) ["", "success", {…}]
v4a: 
v4b: success
v4c: {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
v5a: (3) ["", "success", {…}]
v5b: (3) ["", "success", {…}]
v5c: undefined
v1: (3) ["", "success", {…}]
v2: (3) ["", "success", {…}]
v3: (3) ["", "success", {…}]
v4a: 
v4b: success
v4c: {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
v5a: 
v5b: success
v5c: {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
v6a: (3) ["", "success", {…}]
v6b: (3) ["", "success", {…}]
v6c: undefined
```

For some reason, I thought the code I had relating to the `5` example above was still returning that single response as it does in the `6` example. But apparently I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`$.when.apply` is a bit ugly. Each argument in `then()` or `done()` is an array and the data is one of the elements in the array (I forget the order)

you basically have to do something like:

```
$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
   [].slice.call(arguments).forEach(function(arg){
      var data = arg[1] // guessing at index here, I forget
   });
   // or
   var allData = [].map.call(arguments) ....
});
```

Since modern browsers support Promise API I suggest using Promise.all() instead. All of the jQuery deffered api was conceived before Promises were common place and as a result $.when is still ugly

```
Promise.all(requests).then(function(resultsArray){
   // resultsArray contains data from each request
});
```

Example:

```js
const doRequest = (num) => {
  let url = 'http://httpbin.org/get';
  return $.getJSON(url, {id: num }).then(res => res.args)
}

const requests = [1, 2, 3, 4].map(doRequest);

Promise.all(requests).then(res => console.log(res))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the description, but what I'm specifically curious about is why `$.when.apply()` doesn't give me the `.then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR )` response if it only gets one `deferred` object.. Something makes me think this is somehow related to using `.apply()` in this way, but it's the *not knowing* part that bugs me.

Comment: With that said, `Promise.all()` looks really interesting... I must go do some reading now. :)

Comment: because  those params make up the array for each argument. Note that `$.when` has nothing directly to do with `$.ajax`. It is simply handling what gets returned by prior `then()` and wrapping into array for each argument

Comment: could you perhaps have a look at the JSFiddle I added to my question? I think that may help clarify what it is that I'm trying to understand..

Comment: So, I now understand why my question didn't make sense to anyone else... It was based entirely on an incorrect assumption, where what I *thought* was happening actually wasn't. Everything is indeed working as per the jQuery documentation after all. Thanks for your time anyway. :)